# My ionic 4 app close on back buttion click is worked few days. now it is not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am developing an ionic4 app. after logout I am redirecting to the login page by using this.navController.navigateRoot method. to close the app by clicking the mobile back button I used the following code. it worked for a few days after that now I have to release an updated of this app if click on mobile back button it is not closing the app instead it redirecting to the previous open screen. can anyone help me to solve this issue?
ionic version: 5.2.3
code:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.subscription = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(async () => {
        navigator['app'].exitApp();
    });
}

ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this way  remove `async ()`

```
constructor(public myplatform: Platform)
{}

ionViewDidEnter()
{
      this.backbButtonSubscription = this.myplatform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
          //handle whatever You want
      });
}

ionViewWillLeave(){
      this.backbButtonSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Hope this will help you [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/v4-back-button-doesnt-exit-app-solved-tutorial/149994/5)

Comment: is method firing

Comment: 18:22:10.273 23034-23095/com.ambrotechs.bluebay E/Capacitor/Plugin/Console: Unhandled Promise rejection: StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for t! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: {"ngTempTokenPath":null,"ngTokenPath":["t",null]} Error: StaticInjectorError[t -> t]: 
      StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
        NullInjectorError: No provider for t!

Comment: please add to component.ts and modlude.ts to question

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
   <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

[enter link description here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/back-button)

Comment: I have an issue with mobile h/w back button but not back arrow in app